# jQuery mouse leave enter hide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, mouseenter, mouseleave

Below is my jQuery:

```
$(".notificationfeedlist li").live('mouseleave', function() {
    IF(NOT (MOUSE OVER AN ELEMENT WITH ID INFO))$('#info').hide();
});
```

And here is the HTML I am applying this jQuery to:

```
<div id="info">
    <div class="arrow-right2"></div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
    <div class="scrollerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

What should I replace `IF(NOT (MOUSE OVER AN ELEMENT WITH ID INFO))` with to achieve hiding elements that do *not* have an ID of "info"?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Fair enough the question is a little terse, but remember not everyones' first language is English.

Comment: Please include the code for mouseenter binding, html and/or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".notificationfeedlist li").live('mouseleave',function(e){
    if (e.target.id != "info") {
        $('#info').hide();
    };
});
```

Comment: Why is it not working? It matches the requirement in your OP.

Comment: e.target.id return empty string, so it hide it always weather mouseenter in info or not

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're using this with in your first post, so I can see the structure. Thanks.

Comment: That appears to only be the info section, not the `.notificationfeedlist li` element which the mouse event is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to  class="info" and then check with jQuery .hasClass();

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help: there are no lis in your code; just divs. That could be your problem.